# Where Can I Find All Scope Selectors And Definitions for VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to create my own Visual Studio Code theme. The JSON file for VSC themes consists of an object called `colors`, which contains UI colors, and an array called `tokenColors`, which contains syntax colors (from my understanding).

The VSC documentation for the different `colors` selectors can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color). What I haven't found is a list of the different `tokenColors` and what they mean.

So far, I have found out that you can use the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command to find out what token/scope every word/symbol in your code belongs to. But I can't write code in every language containing every possible code construct and keyword just to then inspect them and find out the scope they belong to.

I also learnt that these scopes are the same or similar to the ones used in [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/scope_naming.html). However, this documentation only contains a small portion of the scopes used in VSC's built in themes. How am I supposed to find out what the remaining scopes stand for?

Answer (score 0):

For syntax highlighting a different set of colors is used, with an own set of token identifiers (aka. scopes). The [Syntax Highlighting Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide) describes details of the tokenization + theming process and refers to the [TextMate](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars) rules, which are used also in VS Code.

This page contains section about naming conventions and that's essentially the base set of token IDs that have become the de-facto standard. Extensions often create their own scopes, but you cannot handle all of them. So, focus on the base set instead.

Fortunately, scope selectors are hierarchically organized. When the highlighter cannot find a color for, say, `keyword.sql.mysql` it tries again with `keyword.sql` or finally with `keyword`. That means, as long as all scopes follow these rules, then there will be at least a color available from the base set.

Answer (score 0):

> > How am I supposed to find out what the remaining scopes stand for?

You cannot simply target each and every possible scope.

I am in the process of creating a Syntax Highlighter for a language that does not have support in VSCode so far. As Mike mentioned, I followed the documentation [Syntax Highlighting guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide). For the scope names, I opened the dark_vs.json file from the extensions\theme-defaults\themes directory and used the scope names available there, in my tmGrammar.json file.

So, as a Theme developer, when you create colors for scope names - make sure most of the scope names mentioned in the default theme files (like dark_vs.json) is covered.